# Filter an object of objects by key

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, object, filter

I'm having an object like this

```
{
  "GroupA": {
    "Parent1": [1, 2, 3],
    "Parent2": [1, 2, 3],
    "Parent12": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  "GroupB": {
    "Parent13": [1, 2, 3],
    "Parent5": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  "GroupC": {
    "Parent7": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

Now i want to filter this object by searching the name of the `Parent`
For example when I search `parent1` the result should be

```
{
  "GroupA": {
    "Parent1": [1, 2, 3],
    "Parent12": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  "GroupB": {
    "Parent13": [1, 2, 3],
  }
}
```

Here is my solution but it's not working correctly if a `Group` has many similar `Parent` name it only return the first one. And when I try to set state it filter like all wrong value

```
let newData = []
let catalogArr = Object.entries(catalogList)

const handleSearchElement = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value
        catalogArr.forEach(catalog => {
            let filteredKeys = Object.keys(catalog[1]).filter(name => name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
            let valuesOfKey
            if(filteredKeys[0]) {
                valuesOfKey = {
                    [filteredKeys[0]]: Object.values(catalog[1][filteredKeys[0]])
                }
                newData.push([catalog[0], {...valuesOfKey}])
            }
        })
        console.log(Object.fromEntries(newData));

        setCatalogList(Object.fromEntries(newData))
        // console.log(catalogList);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to accomplish this pretty easily, however, all of the packing and unpacking of objects using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to essentially treat them as arrays suggests you may be using the wrong data structure.

If you need to do this repeatedly, look into doing a one-off transformation that arranges the data for O(1) access, for example, by grouping on inner keys rather than outer keys (hard to say since I don't know the data or use case). Or, if you're mostly iterating, consider using arrays.

```js
const data = {
  "GroupA": {
    "Parent1": [1, 2, 3],
    "Parent2": [1, 2, 3],
    "Parent12": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  "GroupB": {
    "Parent13": [1, 2, 3],
    "Parent5": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  "GroupC": {
    "Parent7": [1, 2, 3]
  }
};

const targetKey = "parent1";

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  const filtered = Object.entries(v).filter(([k, ]) => 
    k.toLowerCase().includes(targetKey.toLowerCase())
  );
  
  if (filtered.length) {
    a[k] = Object.fromEntries(filtered);
  }
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```